# Error when sync my app, it shows Message: expected start or end tag

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a error when I sync my app, it shows error:

> Message: expected start or end tag

Can anyone tell me how to solve it??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.assignment002" >

//Bluetooth
<uses-feature android:name = "android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


//Internet
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".CustLogin" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".CustSignUp" />
    <activity android:name=".Bluetooth" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is the error the android studio show up:

```
Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\JC\AndroidStudioProjects\Assignment002\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
arseError at [row,col]:[7,5]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: You can't comment with // in xml. In xml is used <!-- to start comment and --> to end comment. Also I see extra ` on the beginning of second line, that you inserted probably accidentally also is wrong.

Comment: Missing Manifest closing tag, last line add `</manifest>`. Wrong way to comment, in XML, use `<!-- Message -->` or Select text and press `ctrl + shift + ?` for multi-line comment or `ctrl + ?` for single-line comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that there are no syntax errors.

Check this out

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" >
    
    <!-- Bluetooth -->
    <uses-feature android:name = "android.hardware.bluetooth" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    
    <!-- Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".CustLogin" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CustSignUp" />
        <activity android:name=".Bluetooth" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Regards...